# Python: How to sum entries in a list with `nan` entries and find mean

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, statistics, mean

I have a list with `nan` entries

```
import numpy as np
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [nan, 2, 3, nan, 5, 6]
c = [nan, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

data = [a,b,c]
```

I want to find the mean of items in the list by summing the ith entries in the list
and dividing by the mean of all its non-NaN elements.

```
mean = np.mean(data)
```

doesn't work since nan entries are found.

For instance in MATLAB  `mean([a;b;c],'omitnan')` option is found.

Is there a similar function in Python?

Suggestions will be really helpful

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you intend to include the NaNs when dividing by the total number of elements in the array to find the mean? Should the mean of `b` be computed as `(2 + 3 + 5 + 6) / 4` or `(2 + 3 + 5 + 6) / 6`?

Comment: @ddejohn (2 + 3 + 5 + 6) / 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is answer that you looking for.

`np.nanmean(data,axis=1)`

The `np.nanmean` is used to calculate the mean of array ignoring the NaN value.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-numpy-nanmean-function/

Answer (score 0):

Numpy offers a convenient function for that! Namely, `nanmean()`, that ignores any `np.nan` entries when computing the mean, i.e.

```
import numpy as np

np.nanmean(a)
>4.0
np.nanmean(b)
>4.0
np.nanmean(c)
>4.0
```

Moreover, `nansum()`, `nanmin()`, `nanmax()` etc. offer nan-insensitive analogues to `sum()`, `min()`, and `max()`.